# Heat capacity at constant volume and energy

Tags: thermodynamics, energy, volume

So, my understanding of heat capacity at constant volume is that

$$C_V = \bigg(\frac{\delta Q}{dT}\bigg)_V$$

So far, so good. But according to my professor,

$$dU = C_VdT$$

for an ideal gas, even when work is performed, that is, when $\delta Q\neq dU$. I see that there are a lot of explanations in this forum as to why the above formula is true, so please note that I am NOT asking that again. What I am asking for is some help understanding how can $C_V$ be equal to two different things at the same time... That looks like a contradiction. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: A number of comments removed. Friendly reminder: to answer a closed question, vote to reopen it. Please don't post answers in the comments.

Comment: I still think it's unclear as to how the other questions were not duplicates

Comment: @Cross Sorry, but it doesn't. The question I'm interested in is a little bit different...

Comment: I believe you. I think more explanation is needed in the question though. Right now I just can't see it, but I'm not trying to say you're wrong.

Comment: That comment was posted for a previous version of the question. Now my comment is irrelevant, but I suggest you add a little more explanation in the question, and make what you're asking more apparent to the others.

Answer (score 0):

I can feel the confusion, at first it seems contradictory, but you actually need to know about nature of $\Delta U$.

There are two functions in thermodynamics:

1. **State Functions**: These functions depend **only** on state variables of system (which describe state of the system like $P,V,T$). $\Delta U$ belongs here.
2. **Path Functions**: These functions depend on path taken to reach one state of system to other state of the system. Path can be Isobaric, Isothermal, Adiabatic, Isochoric, Polytropic or other complex paths. $\Delta Q,\Delta W$ belong here.

Now as you said:
$$C_v=\left(\frac{\Delta Q}{n\Delta T}\right)_v$$

Now from first law of thermodynamics:$\Delta U=\Delta Q-\Delta W$
In isochoric process (volume is constant as described by our first equation), $\Delta W=0$ (Path function).
Hence:$\Delta U=\Delta Q$

Now:
$$C_v=\left(\frac{\Delta U}{n\Delta T}\right)$$
Hence:
$$\Delta U=nC_v\Delta T$$

So while we found this equation in isochoric situation, but $\Delta U$ is state function, it doesn't care which path system is going through! so this established equation is valid for any ideal gas system taking any kind of path.